# How does an element in the cohomology of a sequence of $R$ modules look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, quotient-spaces

Let us assume $I\subset \Bbb{Z}$ and $(M^i)_{i\in I}$ is a sequence of $R$ modules with associated $R$-modules homomorphism $$f^i:M^i\rightarrow M^{i+1}$$ Then we have defined the cohomology $$H^j\left(\left(M^i\right)_{i\in I}\right):=ker(f^j)/Im(f^{j-1})$$ I know that both $ker(f^j)$ and $Im(f^{j-1})$ are submodules since $f^j$ and $f^{j-1}$ are $R$-modules homomorphisms. But now I wonder how an element in this quotient looks like. Is it similar to the quotient of a ring by an ideal?
So I mean if I take $\bar x\in H^j\left(\left(M^i\right)_{i\in I}\right)$ then $x\in ker(f^j)$ and $\bar x=x+Im(f^{j-1})$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, your description is correct. Personally, I would advise you to make sure you're confortable with basic definitions such as quotient modules before you try to look into more advanced topics like cohomology.

Comment: @CaptainLama sorry but I mean if I look at quotients of modules we always have $A$ a module and $B\subset A$ a submodule and then we define $A/B$ with the relation above. But is it here that $Im$ is a submodule of $ker$?

Comment: Yes, because in order to define cohomology you need the property that $f^{i+1}\circ f^i=0$, which is a reformulation of $Im(f^i)\subset Ker(f^{i+1})$.

Comment: @CaptainLama hmm okey thats strange because in our definition the prof has never mention this so our definition really is the following:

A measure of exactess is the cohomology... (here the definition comes in)